# Use set notation to give a description of the set {0,3,6,9,12}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here's my attempt: {x∈Z|0≥x≤12} but my issue is the intervals how do i put more than one rule in this

Comment: Note that only multiples of $3$ are in the given set. You can just add the rule like $\exists y \in \mathbb Z, x = 3y$.

Comment: You've heard of the word "and", right?  PS You mean "$0\le x$" not "$0 \ge x$".

Comment: satisfying close vote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{3n:n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\},n\leq4\}$